# Fastest "Remote Desktop" type program for Windows Vista / 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, software-rec, remote-desktop

I'm running Windows Vista Home Premium on my laptop (which does not include Remote Desktop) and Windows 7 RTM on my Desktop. I'm currently using Ultra VNC to remotely control my Laptop from my Desktop, but screen updates seem a lot slower than it seems like it should be over a 100mbit LAN.

Are there any faster alternatives? Or, what can I do to improve the speed of VNC? I'm currently using it at pretty much its default settings.

Edit -- Ideally free programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fastest RD software I have yet come accross is **[TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/index.aspx)** (free for personal use). of course, Teamviewer can be configured to be used via LAN only.

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remotely access the machine, rather than purchasing another product, I would suggest you upgrade to Vista Business or Vista Ultimate.  The price should be approximately equal to the cost of good third party software, and then it becomes built in and you have added features as well.

Comment: Agreed : As far as I know, Remote Desktop is the fastest, although not as developed in functionality as the VNC variants.

Answer (score 1):

[Italc](http://italc.sourceforge.net/)...designed as a teaching tool, but its super fast and is amazing for this use

Comment: Seems quite nice for teachers! I'm wondering why I have never seen such a tool being used so far...

Comment: The home page states Vista support 'will come'. Have you tried it under Vista / Win 7 ?

Comment: It run on vista, personally i had no problems as an admin, but i think there was a bug with the shutdown and or lock on the clients. But its been a little while since I used it.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the Top 25 of Remote Desktop Apps at Wakoopa.](http://wakoopa.com/categories/utilities/remote-desktop)

These results are based on the usage of a lot of people so they have everything you can dream of.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience UltraVNC had a very reasonable refresh rate when its display driver was installed.
(This remark is of course only useful if you haven't already tried it.)